# Plot German Geographic data in Python using Json file

Tags: python, json, ipython

My iPython interface gives an error when I try ploting geographic CSV Data File using .JSON file.
[The image of my sample data][1]

Here is my python code:

```
data3=DataFrame(df['DropOffDateNumber'].groupby((df['federal_state'])).mean()).reset_index()
state_geo = r'bundeslaender.json'
map = folium.Map(location=[50.810356, 9.925261], zoom_start=3)
```

The output of code looks like:

[Output][2]

I have 2 .JSON files I am trying to use to plot the map:
File1:

```
<a href=http://www.filedropper.com/bundeslaender><img src=http://www.filedropper.com/download_button.png width=127 height=145 border=0/></a><br /><div style=font-size:9px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:127px;font-color:#44a854;> <a href=http://www.filedropper.com >file upload storage</a></div>
```

File2:

```
<a href=http://www.filedropper.com/databundeslander><img src=http://www.filedropper.com/download_button.png width=127 height=145 border=0/></a><br /><div style=font-size:9px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:127px;font-color:#44a854;> <a href=http://www.filedropper.com >online backup</a></div>
```

Here is the code I am running when in iPyhton:

```
map.geo_json(geo_path=state_geo, data=data3,
             columns=['federal_state', 'DropOffDateNumber'],
             key_on='properties.GEN',
             fill_color='BuPu', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
             legend_name='User Retention')
map
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    358         try:
--> 359             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    360         except StopIteration as err:

StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-1c66c89f704c> in <module>()
      3              key_on='properties.GEN',
      4              fill_color='BuPu', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
----> 5              legend_name='User Retention')
      6 map
      7 #.create_map(path='us_states.html')

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py in geo_json(self, *args, **kwargs)
    504         warnings.warn('This method is deprecated. '
    505                       'Please use Map.choropleth instead.')
--> 506         return self.choropleth(*args, **kwargs)
    507 
    508     def choropleth(self, geo_path=None, geo_str=None, data_out='data.json',

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py in choropleth(self, geo_path, geo_str, data_out, data, columns, key_on, threshold_scale, fill_color, fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, legend_name, topojson, reset)
    677             geo_json = TopoJson(geo_data, topojson, style_function=style_function)  # noqa
    678         else:
--> 679             geo_json = GeoJson(geo_data, style_function=style_function)
    680 
    681         self.add_children(geo_json)

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, name, overlay, control)
    299         if hasattr(data, 'read'):
    300             self.embed = True
--> 301             self.data = json.load(data)
    302         elif isinstance(data, dict):
    303             self.embed = True

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    266         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    267         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 268         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    269 
    270 

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    316             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    317             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 318         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    319     if cls is None:
    320         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    341 
    342         """
--> 343         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    344         end = _w(s, end).end()
    345         if end != len(s):

C:\Users\Animesh Dubey\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    359             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    360         except StopIteration as err:
--> 361             raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
    362         return obj, end

ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question as I had this exact error when trying to do something similar in Folium. The problem in my case turned out to be an error in the formatting of the state_geo json file.

I tried to access the json files that you linked to to check whether this was the case for you too, but the links didn't work. If you haven't yet solved this problem I'd recommend double checking the json format.

Comment: thank you Anthr, still trying to solve the problem. Could you please give me your mail id and I can send you the json file to check.

Comment: If you can host it somewhere and provide a link I will take a look.

Comment: Hi Anthr,                                                                                                             above are the links to the 2 files: 1. bundeslander.json which has some problem. 2. is the dataus-states.json which works perfectly fine(for reference). Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I just took a quick look at your code and you have 'key_on='properties.GEN'. but there is no 'GEN' element in your json properties object, only 'properties.name'. Have you tried using '.name' instead of '.GEN' ?